# Why does android device administration not work properly

Tags: android, xml, administration

I am setting two buttons on the screen. Whenever I press the first button it will disable the camera. ( as an admin )

I have set manifest ;

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.firstapplication.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <!-- This is where we register our receiver -->
    <receiver
        android:name=".DemoDeviceAdminReceiver"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_DEVICE_ADMIN" >
        <intent-filter>

            <!-- This action is required -->
            <action android:name="android.app.action.DEVICE_ADMIN_ENABLED" />
        </intent-filter>

        <!-- This is required this receiver to become device admin component. -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.app.device_admin"
            android:resource="@xml/device_admin_sample" />
    </receiver>


</application>
```

I have wrote code as ;

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity  {

static final int ACTIVATION_REQUEST = 47; // identifies our request id
DevicePolicyManager devicePolicyManager;
ComponentName demoDeviceAdmin;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // ...

    // Initialize Device Policy Manager service and our receiver class
    devicePolicyManager = (DevicePolicyManager)getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);
    demoDeviceAdmin = new ComponentName(this, DemoDeviceAdminReceiver.class);
}

/* begin, camera management block */
static boolean click = false ;
private OnClickListener setCamera = new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
      if ( click == false ) {
          startCamera();
          click = true ;
      }
      else {
          stopCamera();
          click = false ;
      }
      activate () ; // activate device policy manager
    }
};
private void startCamera(){
        if(getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA)){ 
            camera.unlock();    
        } else {
                 ;
        }
    }

@SuppressLint("NewApi") private void stopCamera(){
    devicePolicyManager. setCameraDisabled(demoDeviceAdmin, true);
}

/* end, camera management block */
private OnClickListener closeApplication = new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
     finish ();
    }
};
void initializeDPM ( ) {
    if (!devicePolicyManager.isAdminActive(demoDeviceAdmin)) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(DevicePolicyManager.ACTION_ADD_DEVICE_ADMIN);
            intent.putExtra(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_DEVICE_ADMIN,
                    demoDeviceAdmin);
            intent.putExtra(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_ADD_EXPLANATION,
            "Additional text explaining why this needs to be added.");
            startActivityForResult(intent, ACTIVATION_REQUEST);
    } else {
            devicePolicyManager.lockNow();
    }
}

public void activate ( ) {
        // Activate device administration
        Intent intent = new Intent(
        DevicePolicyManager.ACTION_ADD_DEVICE_ADMIN);
        intent.putExtra(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_DEVICE_ADMIN,
        demoDeviceAdmin);
        intent.putExtra(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_ADD_EXPLANATION,
        "told me to do this");
        startActivityForResult(intent, ACTIVATION_REQUEST);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case ACTIVATION_REQUEST:
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                // Has become the device administrator.
            } else {
                //Canceled or failed.
            }
            return;
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

}
```

My admin class

```
public class DemoDeviceAdminReceiver extends DeviceAdminReceiver{
@Override
public void onEnabled(Context context, Intent intent) {
    super.onEnabled(context, intent);

}


@Override
public void onDisabled(Context context, Intent intent) {
    super.onDisabled(context, intent);
    }
}
```

my device_admin_sample  is;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<device-admin xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<uses-policies>
    <limit-password />
    <watch-login />
    <reset-password />
    <force-lock />
    <wipe-data />
    <expire-password />
    <encrypted-storage />
    <disable-camera />
</uses-policies>
</device-admin>


</LinearLayout>
```

Why I could not  close the camera as an admin ?

Comment: First quesiton I have is what version of Android?

Comment: @TheCapn android 4.2 api level 17

Comment: Can you post your resource: device_admin_sample?

Comment: @TheCapn I have edited with new data, you want.

Comment: Where is `initializeDPM` called from? (My apologies if I'm asking seemingly useless questions, I'm trying to get a full understanding of the execution flow of your program to know if any steps on setting up admin were overlooked. Shit happens right?)

Comment: I forget to call this function. Just few minutes ago, I have tried the code with calling it. Result is still application not working

Comment: @TheCapn is the problem related to permission of the hardware camera ?

Comment: Sorry, got pulled away (silly job of mine) -- Your permissions seem alright, my thoughts were that you're incorrectly setting up the instances needed such as calling the initiate function (which you said was fixed). Follow through this linked tutorial and see what you have that is different: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html